# creat a xml with animation arrows

Tags: android

I would like to create a xml in android like below with animation.

Just like what android default behavior with below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6.1" />
    
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/white" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="10" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This default behavior not work for me since my device has disabled animation by default.

[image]